# Unable to write my dataframe using feather (strided data not supported)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, feather

When using the feather package (http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/03/feather-a-fast-on-disk-format-for-data-frames-for-r-and-python-powered-by-apache-arrow/) to try and write a simple 20x20 dataframe, I keep getting an error stating that strided data isn't yet supported. I don't believe my data is strided (or out of the ordinary), and I can replicate the sample code given on the website, but can't seem to get it to work with my own. Here is some sample code:

```
import feather
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tempArr = reshape(np.arange(400), (20,20))
df = pd.DataFrame(tempArr)
feather.write_dataframe(df, 'test.feather')
```

The last line returns the following error:

```
FeatherError: Invalid: no support for strided data yet
```

I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04. Am I perhaps misunderstanding something about how pandas dataframes are stored?

Comment: reshape generate a view, it can be a pb.  try tempArr=tempArr.copy() before.

Comment: @B.M. thanks for the suggestion! Just added that line right in between creating tempArr and creating the DataFrame, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please come to GitHub: https://github.com/wesm/feather/issues/97

Bug reports do not belong on StackOverflow

Comment: In essence,  as explained in the link, the issue can be solved by doing `df = df.copy()` before writing df to a feather file.